# Why do I get a CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT when trying to http post?

Tags: http, post, curl

Here's the code (extracted from an existing application):

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
_ASSERTE(curl);

string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";

char *data = "mode=test";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

bool success = (res == CURLE_OK);

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

The value of `res` is `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT`. Is this URL not compatible with curl?

Comment: what is the type of m_checkUrl?  Have you tested with an inline char * ? i.e. putting "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" in the third param to curl_easy_setopt?

Comment: that url was supposed to have an http: prefix

Comment: I've updated my code sample - I was using string instead of char * - oops!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, simple mistake, I need to pass `char *` to `curl_easy_setopt` and not `string`. To fix this I've just used `.c_str()` like so:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
_ASSERTE(curl);

string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";

char *data = "mode=test";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

bool success = (res == CURLE_OK);

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```