# Nested libcurl request c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, libcurl

My question would be how would I do a nested curl request because my current code is this and does not work. I does not work as I can see the requests going to my server and there is only one which is a GET request.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

int rad = rand() % 100000;
std::string agent_name = "https://127.0.0.1:443/agent/" + std::to_string(rad);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURLcode res;
  CURL *curl;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://127.0.0.1:443/");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);

  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  
  if (res == CURLE_OK) {
    long response_code;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
    if (response_code == 200)
    {
      std::cout << "Hello";
      CURLcode ret;
      CURL *hnd;

      hnd = curl_easy_init();
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, agent_name);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);

      ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);

      curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
      hnd = NULL;

    }
    else { }
  }
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  curl = NULL;

}
```

This prints Hello to stdout but does not run the curl POST request, so How would one do a nested curl request.

EDIT: I tried removing the if statement. So my question is how does one do two libcurl requests

Comment: You need to check if hnd is a valid handle (not NULL)

Comment: Apart from using `std::string` and `<iostream>`, this is not a C++ but rather a C problem.  What's the value of the `ret` variable (which seems to be completely unused btw) after `curl_easy_perform(hnd)`?

Comment: @taiBsu the value of ret is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `curl_easy_perform(hnd)` returns `3`:

Via [cURL](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html):

**CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT (3)**

*The URL was not properly formatted.*

You will have to pass a `char *` instead of a `std::string` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827837/why-do-i-get-a-curle-url-malformat-when-trying-to-http-post)):

`curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, agent_name.c_str());`